# Sharing different type of data on facebook with one meta tags

Tags: php, facebook

How can be accomplish this scenario. 
There are 3 pages - `image.php`, `video.php` and `gifs.php`. In each of them I include files - `header.php` and `footer.php` i.e. same header and footer for them.

Now how can I have share button for facebook on each of them when **META** tags for facebook are same? i.e.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:image" content=""/>
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="" />
```

Is it possible with one `header` file to show different values here and when I hit share button if I'm on `video.php` to share desired video or if is `gifs.php` share the gif?

Or I must have different header file for each page?

Comment: are you facing any issue in implementing the your solution

Comment: I don't even know how to implement it. I know how but for one page. What I need to put in `<meta property="og:image" content=""/>` to take dynamic content for 3 pages? If it was only for `image.php` I will put `<meta property="og:image" content="$image"/>` but for 3 ?

Comment: update your question for wat you want to display for 3 pages the meta property or they must be same

Comment: As I said in my question - I have 3 pages with dynamical content. How to make it when user is on page `video.php` and watching video to be able to share that video on facebook. Then the user go to images and he want to share some image... all the pages are with one `header.php` file which contain meta tags.. What I don't understand is how to make this... obviously I can't put 3 times same meta tags in the head each for different page..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_model

Comment: Can't you make your header dynamic? And ensure that the correct meta tags are added to it based on the page that you are viewing? e.g. for `image.php` your header will have `<meta property="og:image"` , for `video.php` your header will have `<meta property="og:video"` etc.

Comment: @Bangdel, yes this is what I think will do the trick but I don't know how to make this.

Comment: Well then if you cannot make the header dynamic then don't use it. Create the header and add the meta tags in the respective file itself.

Comment: @Bangdel, what this mean `Create the header and add the meta tags in the respective file itself`...?